# WSO2 EI, change the structure of response to client that is received from backend

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a REST API service which I want expose to other application as REST API, by using enterprise integrator. When client makes request to exposed service, WSO2 EI makes request to backend and forards to client it's response.

[According to this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Transforming+Message+Content) I can transform structure of clients request.

Is it possible to change structure of backend response before forwarding it to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, in the same manner as you do in the InSequence you can create a mapping in the OutSequence as well.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Can I change structure if response depending on values that sent by backend? For example, client made request, EI made request to backend, backend sent response to EI and EI uses some kind of `id else` logic by using response values and creates send response to client.

Comment: There are multiple mediators you can use in your (out) sequence to make content based decisions. For example the Filter and Switch mediators. These allow for simple decision making that can influence your mediation flow to return different results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Define your custom Synapse configuration in Out sequence. Try Developer studio or use the web UI.